# Не удается скачать картинку товара через API МойСклад

Tags: php, moysklad-json-api, мойсклад-api, мойсклад

Получаем список товаров
https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.2/entity/product/?limit=10&offset=0

далее получаем перечень картинок
https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.2/entity/product/002930f2-ad87-11e9-912f-f3d4000b4599/images

получаем ссылку на скачивание картинки
https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.2/download/98505406-021a-4007-a6a1-6194bb7a295c

из запроса cUrl получаем ссылку непосредственно для скачивания картинки
https://storage.files.mo01.cloud.servers.com:8080/v1/SERVERSCOM_2ce3101fed274bd6b24d2124be063f47/image-prod/image/a25acf93-16db-11e7-7a69-971100003486/goodimage/5fb19582-4626-4718-bd7d-eb0169a2cd0e?temp_url_sig=f911543e6c3bbf1c59ddc3d3b6f9fb5cd542edaa&temp_url_expires=1575317985&filename=nauwzqcf2a8c04w0gocg0g4kgwk04s.jpg

но скачать картинку не удается
Ошибка curl: couldn't connect to host 
а в браузере эта ссылка отдает 401 Unauthorized: Temp URL invalid

и самое интересное - все работает на обычном хостинге, но не работает на VPS
куда копать?

Comment: Пробовали? https://support.moysklad.ru/hc/ru/community/posts/115007123067-%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена. Оказалось что после установки Битрикс на VPS, Битрикс устанавливает файервол с запретом на порт 8080, через который как раз и скачиваются картинки с МойСклад